# Cell Contents as Part of a 'WHERE' Statement in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, powerquery

I have been searching for weeks but haven't had much success in finding an answer to the following question...

Can I create a text-box in in Excel (in developer options) and then have the user-entered contents of the text-box be part of a WHERE statement in SQL (T-SQL)? Ideally, I would like the user to be able to enter a 3-digit ID number and then hit a search button to bring up a list of results on either the same or different sheet. If a text-box isn't simple then I will settle for the contents of a cell being the referenced in place of the text-box contents.

Something like this:

```
SELECT T.CustomerName, T.NetAmount, T.TransactionType

FROM TheDatabase.dbo.TransactionsTable T

WHERE T.ScheduledDate > '2016-01-01' AND 
     (T.Status = 'InProcess' OR T.Status = 'Completed') AND
      T.CustomerID = [textbox1.contents / cell(A1).. something]
```

I know SQL isn't designed to work like this, but I hope it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

Some background:

I am passing some responsibilities to a co-worker because I am moving to a different role. I have a report I run periodically that gives me statistics about accounts payable transactions. I had to learn some basic SQL over night and have been pretty successful in designing SELECT statements and learning as I go. The problem is that whenever I need to add a new customer (which is basically a 3-digit number) to my list of accounts to review, I have to modify the query. This is no big deal for me, I just open PowerQuery, select advanced view, and edit the code. I can't be fixing the tool for the next person, so I need a way they can just search for the customer they want.

I COULD load all customers, but there are over 3.6 million transactions in the primary table with over 30 fields that we look at. PLUS there are at least 6 tables in 3 databases that I join together to pull and calculate all the info. The last time I attempted to retrieve all the transactions data it put me out of production because of my system running out of memory. The only time I successfully queried that much data it took almost 10 minutes. Honestly, that wasn't a problem for me, but this person will have to run this all the time and I need to speed things up. The only way to eliminate the problem, as I can see it, is to only pull the transactions I need. When I do this now, it takes like 3 seconds.

The query I've been using was created in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I basically copy the query and paste it into the 'advanced' box when creating a query in Excel.

Any advice that can be given about this would be helpful, both now and for future projects!

Comment: first, you are looking for `IN` clause `WHERE T.CustomerID IN (list of comma separated int values, or one column query resulset)`

Comment: second, not sure how you manage to execute SQL statement. Is it inside Excel?

Comment: third, it looks like an XY Problem, try to describe your actual need not your approach to a solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA you can open a SQL Connection to your Database.  But you need the right permissions and passwords to do this.  Maybe a tech person at your company can help with this.

Then you need to build your SQL code and send it.  Then retrieve the results.  You can display the results in multiple ways.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strSQLText As String   ' Declare a string to build your SQL in

    'Open your connection
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz;"
    objMyConn.Open

    strSQLText = "SELECT T.CustomerName, T.NetAmount, T.TransactionType " & _
                 "FROM TheDatabase.dbo.TransactionsTable T " & _
                 "WHERE T.ScheduledDate > '2016-01-01' AND " & _
                 "(T.Status = 'InProcess' OR T.Status = 'Completed') AND " & _
                 "T.CustomerID = '" & _
                 Me.textbox1.Value & "';"

    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

    objMyRecordset.Open strSQLText            

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

This code assumes your T.CustomerID is a varchar.  If it is an integer (or other datatype) you'll need to remove the single quotes from the SQLText that surround the `textbox1.Value`

You may also want to save your results somewhere other than cell "A1".  There are lots of ways/places to display results.

Also, this code assumes `textbox1.Value` has only one ID in it. Get this SQL working with only 1 Customer Code first.  If you *need* to return data for multiple customers, you can do that later with only a little more effort.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Also note that this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I'm fairly sure that if I enter `'; drop table TheDatabase.dbo.TransactionsTable;--`, your entire TransactionsTable will be gone.

Comment: @Nzall:  Very true.  Whenever you want to build quick beginner level SQL that allows users to input data that is spliced into the code, you open it up for bad players to cause havoc.  To alleviate this problem, you need to learn coding techniques that pass variables through as parameters.  Hopefully the beginners at his company are not looking to destroy their data.  But if that is a true concern, they should have a database programmer  at the company write the code for them.  A DBA who is truly worried won't give them the connection string info to begin with.  Good thing to point out Nzall.

Comment: @abraxascarab IMHO it's better to learn the proper habits (parmeterized queries) at the outset than to learn to query via string concatenation, then have to un-learn that later.

Comment: @alroc: Very true.  However, the OP states he's switching jobs and it's not clear he is going to be a programmer.  Ideally, a company should have a programmer doing this query for him. Plus his explanation is a little vague.  And since no one else is helping him, my response points him toward a simple answer that works.  I was actually hoping someone would be more altruistic with their time and write a beginners explanation of parameterized queries for him.  Hint hint. :)

Comment: The database I'm working in is a read-only backup we make every night. We backup then copy the backup and that's the database we pull our stats from. The drop command throws an error besides the fact that only a handful of people use it. If something does go wrong, we just do a full backup that night instead of a differential - problem solved.

Comment: Also, the engineers at my job are waaaay too busy for this kind of thing. My job is just managing accounts. The basic SQL I've learned was sourced from a 20 minute brain picking session with our DB guy and reading online... namely here. I'm trying my best to learn this piece by piece but the lack of formal training makes it tough.. pieces are missing but I don't know what the puzzle looks like in the end so I don't even know which. I'm just trying to improve my tool for someone elsr  to help them manage accounts.

Comment: Also, how do i use parameters? Ive heard this a few times and if I were able to pass in a value at the beginning that sounds like it would work. I can teach this guy to use PowerQuery. I can't teach SQL because I know him. As soon as he sees code he'll disengage.

Comment: @earthbornLogic: Your explanation of your situation is as I'd imagined.  The above code will get you started.  From there, you can research using parameters.  (Something to aim for if you continue to grow your programming skills.)  Get the connection string info from your DBA and  establish a connection.  As long as you only use a select, you won't damage your backup database.